# What is the difference between IntelliJ "ignored files" and the .gitignore

Tags: intellij-idea, gitignore

IntelliJ offers a dialog for ["ignored files"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/ignored-files.html) which does not pull in data from the .gitignore file I have in my base directory.  Should the ignored files dialog be used?  Does it create a .gitignore file anywhere?  I'm going through [this tutorial](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Using_Git_Locally).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This dialog will ignore files only when working with IDEA, while `.gitignore` should be used for excluding files globally, either when working with version control from IDEA or from the command line `git`.

This dialog doesn't create `.gitignore`.

Comment: So would I want the ignore files to be a subset of .gitignore?  Are there scenarios where this would not be true?

Comment: Use `.gitignore`, see also the [related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60354).

Comment: What's even much more worrisome is that the IDEA ignored files are stored in the `workspace.xml` file, which shouldn't be stored in version control. This means that other people won't see the ignored files and will get a diff on files you've excluded. The only real solution here is to use `.gitignore`. +1